# Can I modify Designer.vb (form designer) to remove a DataSet control from winforms windows?

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0, windows-forms-designer

I am attempting to update an existing winforms application, that was created with a dataset control on all the winforms pages. I have ported it from VS 2008 to VS 2010 and I need to update the database section and connect it to the SQL backend using traditional code method.

In the Solution explorer, when I click on the Dataset files, and click "Exclude From project" I am unable to build the project.

Is it advisable to comment out the code lines that refer to the dataset in the .designer.vb files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you comment the lines from the Designer file, they will just get removed once resaved.

The designer code file is generated when the Form is saved, so it'll just overwrite it. I've done this a few times when things have gone wrong. Make sure you have a backup though!

Comment: cool, so you did not encounter anything that made you regret it?

Comment: good question, I only really regret using WinForms at all (nahh not really). I've got a form which has about 1000 controls on it, and providing you're careful it seems to be ok. Make sure you have the Form designer closed, save the Designer.vb file, rebuild, then try opening the form. Also, there are loads of places to look out for. Datasets are in the Friend WithEvents bit, the beginning of InitializeComponent() and potentially the EndInit() section at the end. You'll know, it'll all be highlighted once you start removing it from the Friend WithEvents, as it won't be declared. Good luck!